# Display the value of a POM file property on an HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, html, maven

I am trying to display the value of a property of my pom.xml file on an HTML page, on the client side (so that an admin can see it on the administration page) but I can't find a way to do it.

I have tried with PHP and JS and so on but nothing is working... Here's my last attempt:

```js
function populatePre(url) {
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById('contents').textContent = this.responseText;
 };
 xhr.open('GET', url);
 xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<p id="testButton"><button type="button" onclick=populatePre('C:\path\to\my\pom.xml')>Click Me!</button></p>
 <pre id="contents"></pre>
```

Basically, the HTML page is in a folder and the pom.xml file is in another one (../../path/to/pom.xml). I don't know how to access it nor how to read it...

Comment: Is HTML page part of maven project?

Comment: It is part of maven project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way by doing this and then sending the value to the view. Here's the code (simplified):

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $pom = '../../path/to/file/pom.xml';

    $myFile = fopen($pom, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $fileContents = fread($myFile, filesize($pom));
    $tempString = substr($fileContents, strpos($fileContents, 'valueToFind') + 49, 50);
    $foundValue = substr($tempString, 0, strpos($tempString, '<')); fclose($myFile);

    return view('administration.index', ['foundValue' => $foundValue]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to describe HTML page as filtered resource in pom.xml. Something like

```
<resource>
    <directory>path/to/html_directory</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>your.html</include>
    </includes>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

Then put placeholder into HTML as `${yourPropertyName}` and it will be substituted with property value during build process. For details see [Maven Resources Plugin filtering option description](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). Will this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here : `C:\path\to\my\pom.xml`, it's a path to your computer, you need to use a server. Basically, you url must be like `localhost:8080/path/to/my/pom.xml` or `your-site.com/path/to/my/pom.xml`. So use an Apache server if you already use PHP.

Comment: It's on my computer because the server is local (for now)

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that because my document root is set to a folder and in order to get to the pom.xml file I need to go to its parent folder.

Comment: Look at the console in your browser, I think it displays `cross origin request blocked`. If its just a root folder problem, you can change it easily.

Comment: I can't change the root folder because the entire application depends on its value. If I change it, I'll have a very big regression

Comment: What about symlinks ? Of course if you are running an Apache server

Comment: What are symlinks?

Comment: A symlink is a link to another file, it doesnt contain the data of the file, like shortcut in Windows.

Comment: you can change it in it "normal" folder, the shortcut permits to put it to the public